# Vue computed property overwriting global state without vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a list of people who have scores. In state I have them listed in an array, one of the items in the array is 'scoreHistory' which is an array of objects containing their scores at different points in time. I want to filter this set for different time periods i.e. -5 days, -30 days so instead of just seeing the overall score I can see the scores if everyone started at 0 say 30 days ago.

I have it (kind of) working. See my code below:

```
filteredScores () {
  if(!this.people) {
    return
  }
  // Here I was trying to ensure there was a copy of the array created in order to not change the original array. I thought that might have been the problem.
  let allPeople = this.people.slice(0) // this.people comes from another computed property with a simple getter. Returns an array.

  let timeWindow = 30 //days
  const windowStart = moment().subtract(timeWindow,'days').toDate()

  for (const p of allPeople ) {
    let filteredScores = inf.scoreHistory.filter(score => moment(score.date.toDate()).isSameOrAfter(windowStart,'day'))

    p.scoreHistory=filteredScores
    //calculate new score
    p.score = inf.scoreHistory.reduce(function(sum,item) {
        return sum + item.voteScore
      },0)
  }
  return allInf
}
```

I expected it to return to me a new array where each person's score is summed up over the designated time period. It seems to do that OK. The problem is that it is altering the state that this.people reads from which is the overall data set. So once it filters all that data is gone. I don't know how I am altering global state without using vuex??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I don't know how I am altering global state without using vuex?" You are doing it because you are modifing array which has referance to state. Vuex is just object.

Make real copy of things you want to sort and problem solved.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the response. I thought splice returned a new array. I also tried [...this.people]. How exactly do you mean? I'm learning here

Comment: Quick trick just to see if it's working would be `const allPeople = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.people));` but it is not recommended. Better google out `deep copy` or `deep clone`

Comment: @AdamOrlov again thank you very much - I did look into deep copies. So much out there I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you're modifying the array, but that you're modifying the objects within the array. You change the scoreHistory and score property of each item in the array. What you want to do instead is create a new array (I recommend using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) where each item is a copy of the existing item plus a new score property.

```
filteredScores () {
  if(!this.people) {
    return
  }

  let timeWindow = 30 //days
  const windowStart = moment().subtract(timeWindow,'days').toDate()

  return this.people.map(p => {
    let filteredScores = p.scoreHistory.filter(score => moment(score.date.toDate()).isSameOrAfter(windowStart,'day'))

    //calculate new score
    let score = filteredScores.reduce(function(sum, item) {
      return sum + item.voteScore
    }, 0)

    // Create a new object containing all the properties of p and adding score
    return {
      ...p,
      score
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you very much. This is working perfectly now. I think I need to become more comfortable with map.